# Messages arrive later but expire first

Tags: rabbitmq

RabbitMQ supports per-message TTL, but I found if the first message has long TTL and the second message has short TTL (expires faster), the second will not be send to dead letter queue (DLQ) until the first is expired.

Is it possible to expire messages according to individual expiration regardless of their position in the queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RabbitMQ strictly follows the FIFO message ordering.
It will only go and process for the next message until the head message in the queue ( the first message in the queue ) gets expired and it is discarded or dead lettered to other exchange.

[Documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html#per-message-ttl-caveats)

> Queues that had a per-message TTL applied to them retroactively (when
> they already had messages) will discard the messages when specific
> events occur. Only when expired messages reach the head of a queue
> will they actually be discarded (or dead-lettered).

Comment: Thanks, I just realized what was the case.

Comment: You can have fixed ttl queues for examle,
1. queue.5sec.dlx
2. queue.10sec.dlx
3. queue.15sec.dlx
etc. This way no messages will be blocked. And all messages will get re-queued back to the main queue after the expected delay.

Comment: Yes that is probably the only way to go, if we do not use the delayed message plugin. Just that if we need 10 distinct TTLs, then we will have to have 10 queues.